# How to get shape / polygon / bounding path / frame of element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

In jQuery, `zepto.js` etc you can say

```
var position = $('a:first').position();
```

But the a-tag can span over several lines with a shape more complex than a simple rectangle (position and size). What I would like to get is the path of the element.

Example

```
The pipes in this examples is meant to illude ||||||| 
|||||| |||| || ||||||| an a-tag spanning over two lines. 
Consisting of two different rects OR 8 different points.
```

So, is there any way to get the polygon of any element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/EEVV2/

This will give you the bounding points of each line of a link.

Since building a poly will depend on the shape, I didn't really have time to get into this, but I think this is a reasonable starting point.

Hope it helps!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var words = $('a').text().split(' '); //break the link's words into array
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    words[i] = '<span>' + words[i] + '</span> '; //wrap each word in a span
}
words.join(' '); //join the words
$('a').html(words); //replace the link html with the words wrapped in spans

var points = []; //to store our points
var lastIndex = $('a span').length - 1; //so we know we've hit the last point
var first; //keep track of first point

$('a span').each(function (i) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    if (i > 0) {
        if (i != lastIndex) {
            if (points[points.length - 1].top < pos.top) { //have we hit a new line?
                var newPos = $($('a span')[i - 1]).position();
                if (newPos.left != first.left) { //check if we are on the right side of the object
                    newPos.left += $($('a span')[i - 1]).width(); //add the width of the word
                    points.push(newPos); //push this point
                } else {
                    points.push(newPos); //we are on the left side, push the point without the width of the word
                }
                //$($('a span')[i - 1]).addClass('red'); //useful for debugging
            }
        } else {
            var bottomLineHeight = $(this).height();
            pos.left += $(this).width(); //add width to last point
            pos.top += bottomLineHeight; //add height to last point, push later
            points[points.length - 1].top += bottomLineHeight; //add height to second to last point
            points.push(pos); //push last point
        }
    } else {
        points.push(pos); //push first point
        first = pos; //keep track of topLeft point (first)
    }
});

//for printing out points
var html = '';
$(points).each(function (i, obj) {
    html += '<p>(' + obj.left + ', ' + obj.top + ')';
});
$('#result').html(html);

});//ready
```

Comment: Great! Is it heavy on the CPU you think? You are basically wrapping each word in a span, updating the DOM and then getting the position for eahch word?

Comment: Yes that is the approach. It will crank a little bit on the CPU, but for 50-100 words it's probably reasonable.I also noticed that the right most words will need the width added to them and the bottom words need the height, I've updated the fiddle and the code.